# Strict Regular Expressions

Tags: php, regex

Is there any way to make regex not return here? As in, I want it to not return strings that are not *exactly* 8 digits.

```
preg_match_all( '/\w+\d{8}', 'word123456789', ret );
```

Comment: If you only want strings that are exactly 8 digits, why are you including the `\w+`? Or do you only want strings ending with exactly 8 digits?

Comment: What you mean by Not return?

Comment: Do you mean 8 numbers or total characters? Do you need at least one letter? Please be specific.

Comment: I want strings that end with exactly 8 digits, if there is more it should be ignored

Comment: Should something like `1word123456789` match successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\w+ will also match digits.  If you want to return only strings that END in exactly 8 digits, then perhaps:

```
'/\b[A-Za-z]+\d{8}\b/'
```

Edit:  That should read strings that start with only letters and end with exactly eight digits.  If you want something else, please clarify

Answer (score 0):

You could use something along these lines:

```
'\w+(?<!\d)\d{8}\b'
```

`\w+` - Any word character occuring 1 or more times

`(?<!\d)\d{8}` - Any 8 digits not preceded by another digit.

`\b` - word boundary.

```
word12345678          - Match
word123456789         - No Match
1word12345678         - Match
1w123456789rd12345678 - Match
```